# How do I include specs for a base class in the specs for an inherited class?

Tags: c#, mspec

I have an `RSSDataSourceParser` class which is fully covered by MSpec specifications. I also have an inherited class, `MultimediaRSSDataSourceParser`. It does all of the parent functionality plus recognition of iTunes RSS extensions. I covered the extended functionality in separate specifications.

However, the business people who read the test suite only see the extended specifications for the `MultimediaRSSDataSourceParser`. They want to see the inherited functionality from `RSSDataSourceParser`, too.

Copying these specifications sounds absurd and would probably cause future code management problems. Is there any way to inherit the specifications from the parent?

Comment: Come back and accept an answer, Antony!

Answer (score 8):

MSpec has pretty useful behaviours that make reuse like this pretty easy. http://lostechies.com/jamesgregory/2010/01/18/behaviours-in-mspec/

Answer (score 1):

I image the two types implement the same interface, or are at least inherited, when you say "it does all the parent [functionality]". You want to use MSpec's `Behaves_like` feature.

> "Behaviours define reusable specs that encapsulate a particular set of, you guessed it, behaviours; you’re then able to include these specs in any context that exhibits a particular behaviour." -- [James Gregory](http://jagregory.com/writings/behaviours-in-mspec/)

I don't know how an RSS data source reader works, so let me show you some example code where I used behaviors. I needed to convert an integer power of 2 (0, 1, 2, 4, etc) from some goofy API into an A-Z character. So, the specifications would be

```
It should_convert_0_to_A = () => _converter.Convert(0).ShouldEqual('A');
It should_convert_1_to_B = () => _converter.Convert(1).ShouldEqual('B');
// ... and so on ...
It should_convert_16777216_to_Z = () => _converter.Convert(16777216).ShouldEqual('Z');
```

But, I had three different implementations of the interface. They included a [binary conversion](https://gist.github.com/996982#file_binary_unit_mask_converter.cs), a [log conversion](https://gist.github.com/996982#file_log_unit_mask_converter.cs), and a [lookup table](https://gist.github.com/996982#file_lookup_unit_mask_converter.cs).

```
public interface IUnitMaskConverter
{
    char Convert(uint mask);
}
```

I wasn't going to copy 26 specifications three or more times! So, I set the specs into a `Behaviors` class

```
[Behaviors]
public class UnitMaskConverterBehaviors
{
    It should_convert_0_to_A = () => _converter.Convert(0).ShouldEqual('A');
    It should_convert_1_to_B = () => _converter.Convert(1).ShouldEqual('B');
    // ... and so on ...
    It should_convert_16777216_to_Z = () => _converter.Convert(16777216).ShouldEqual('Z');

    protected static IUnitMaskConverter _converter;
}
```

So, then it's pretty easy to write a specs class that says *this* implementation *behaves like* a "unit mask converter"

```
[Subject(typeof(IUnitMaskConverter))]
public class When_converting_unit_masks_by_lookup
{
    Behaves_like<UnitMaskConverterBehaviors> a_unit_mask_converter;
    protected static LookupUnitMaskConverter _converter = new LookupUnitMaskConverter();
}

[Subject(typeof(IUnitMaskConverter))]
public class When_converting_unit_masks_by_log
{
    Behaves_like<UnitMaskConverterBehaviors> a_unit_mask_converter;
    protected static LogUnitMaskConverter _converter = new LogUnitMaskConverter();
}

[Subject(typeof(IUnitMaskConverter))]
public class When_converting_unit_masks_by_binary
{
    Behaves_like<UnitMaskConverterBehaviors> a_unit_mask_converter;
    protected static BinaryUnitMaskConverter _converter = new BinaryUnitMaskConverter();
}
```

The report even has all the behaviors listed per implementation.

---

## IUnitMaskConverter specifications

*4 contexts, 108 specifications*

### When converting unit masks by binary

*26 specifications*

- should convert 0 to A
- should convert 1 to B
- ...
- should convert 16777216 to Z

### When converting unit masks by lookup

*26 specifications*

- should convert 0 to A
- should convert 1 to B
- ...
- should convert 16777216 to Z

Comment: You have put the *Because* (`_converter.Convert()`) into the behavior. Isn't that a bad idea?

Comment: @bitbonk, maybe? Would you rather 26 `Behaviors` like `A_converter_for_0`, `A_converter_for_1`, etc? In this case, with no side effects, and one method, I settled.

Comment: @bitbon, the `RssDataReader` in question probably has enough behavior and a large enough API to write the behaviors a little more strictly: only `It` statements in the behavior and the actual behavior in the test class `Because`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the case because testsuite for the **RssDatasourceParser** might be contained from large number of contexts. This means again lots of writing.

Comment: The author says that the extended functionality is covered in a separate class. And it sounds like that extended functionality is really cohesive (supporting the iTunes RSS format). Behaviors should help in this case.